# Couldn't find babel-loader. This error was suddenly showed. Does anyone have any way around this, please?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, webpack, babeljs

```
> clubhouse-landing@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

Cannot find module 'babel-loader
Require stack:
- C:\Users\dwai\Documents\GitHub\Clubhouse-Roomfeed\clubhouse-landing\node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js
- C:\Users\dwai\Documents\GitHub\Clubhouse-Roomfeed\clubhouse-landing\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js        
PS C:\Users\dwai\Documents\GitHub\Clubhouse-Roomfeed\clubhouse-landing>
```

**Where Clubhouse-Roomfeed is the directory of my project and clubhouse-landing is the Create-react-App folder that I Created.**

Comment: > This error suddenly popped, upon trying to run npm start

Comment: We'll need a bit more than copy/paste from the command line. There are dozens of possible issues. You'll need to rule a few of them out before we can help. Have you verified that `babel-loader` is installed? Which module is trying to use it? These are just a few basic questions to get started, but there will be more depending on how you answer those.